# Can not display"■" correctly in word generating from openxml

Tags: openxml

I have to generate docx from word template. I try to display a "■" symbol in openxml by using word bookmark from word template, but it always show ? symbol as following.
[image]

Look the following code, the **value** is ■ ,but it generate ? as above

Run run = new Run();

```
        if (runProperties != null)   //get initial run properties            
        {
              run.AppendChild(runProperties);
        }
        
        //setting bookmark
        run.AppendChild(new Text(value));
```

What can I do to solve the error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two things you can check: the encoding and the font.

Comment: It displays Traditional Chinese well, I changed font, the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I change the code to the following. It works

```
Run run = new Run(new SymbolChar() { Font = "DengXian", Char = "25A0" });
```